Include .env file in maven failsafe plugin
I have a java project with integration tests that I want to run in the maven verify step, but those tests require an .env file with login credentials to run. I couldn't find anything about how to include the file when the rests are run. Does anyone have a suggestion?
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

